# Python3 script with Apache2 not fully working

Tags: python-3.x, apache

My working python3 CLI script fails to fully work when launched from apache2 because of some modules seemingly not being recognized? When calling it with PHP, it seems to fully work but certain modules caused it to fail...

For example I had to comment out plotly.XXXX or it said module not found, apache log:

```
File "/var/www/pythonhack_site/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    import plotly.figure_factory as ff
ImportError: No module named 'plotly.figure_factory'
```

Sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import requests, enchant, urllib.request, socket
import argparse, os, ssl, re, sys, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
# from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
# import plotly.graph_objects as go
# import plotly
# import numpy as np
```

additionally I had to remove my code that used enchant Dict() :

```
#d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
```

because in the apache log it complained:

```
File "/var/www/pythonhack_site/test.py", line 259, in get_general_word_counts
    d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
AttributeError: module 'enchant' has no attribute 'Dict'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. The pip3 modules I installed didn't have permissions in Linux to use so chown fixed it (e.g. sudo chown apache:apache -R /path/to/modules/dir)